# How to stop auto smoothing of freehand sketches in Preview?

Tags: preview

How do i stop this smoothing option from occuring automatically after every free hand sketch because i have to continuously remove the smoothing after every line drawn. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem.  When I use the freestyle draw my lines stay as however I've drawn them.

Answer (score 0):

Only 6,5 half years late but (in the new version of preview) the answer is to use the 'draw' tool, it does not autoreplace shapes:
[image]

Comment: Version number of Preview?